# Different unit testing coverage branch with different env variables

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, istanbul

I don't think that unit testing coverage should depend on env variables, and I would like to know how can I deal with it.

- Using Istanbul

The coverage is lower when I run the tests with envs, in this part:

```
host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || 'localhost'
```

because with this the last branch never is reach.

I think that is related with https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/969
and I was thinking to do `del process.env` starting the tests

What do you think about that? Do you know another way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

With [nconf](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf) helps, I just need to define a default config.